# I am trying to output data in my terminal upon a tkinter button click, I am getting this error but I am not sure where I am going wrong

Tags: python, algorithm, tkinter, data-structures

I am trying to output data in my terminal upon a tkinter button click, I am getting this error but I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Error: failed to get odds: status code 404, response body <!doctype html>

404 Not Found

## Not Found

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import requests
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

sports_window = Tk()
sports_window.wm_title("SportsBook")

pd.set_option("display.max_columns", 100)
pd.set_option("display.width", 1000000)

API_KEY = "api_key_placeholder"

SPORT = "upcoming"

REIGONS = "us"

MARKETS = "h2h"

ODDS_FORMAT = "american"

DATE_FORMAT = "iso"

def get_odds():
    sportsodds_endpoint = e1.get()  # !!!!!!!!
    games = requests.get(
        f"https://api.the-odds-api.com/v4/sports/{SPORT}/odds" + sportsodds_endpoint,
        params={
            "api_key": API_KEY,
            "regions": REIGONS,
            "markets": MARKETS,
            "oddsFormat": ODDS_FORMAT,
            "dateFormat": DATE_FORMAT,
        },
    )

    if games.status_code != 200:
        print(
            f"failed to get odds: status code {games.status_code}, response body {games.text}"
        )
        # GRABS GAME'S TIMES, MATCHUP, AND ODDS BASED OFF OF LEAGUE/SPORT_KEY ENTRY
    else:
        games_json = games.json()
        games_df = pd.DataFrame(games_json)
        league = input(sportsodds_endpoint)
        # FOR LOOP INTERATING OVER THE ENTIRE DF, THEN GRABS LIST OF GAME/ODD DATA BASED OFF OF ENTRY IF VALID ENTRY IS ENTERED
        for sports in games_df:
            np.where(league is True)
            data_filtered = games_df[games_df["sport_key"] == league]

            # PRINTS GAME DATA ^^^^^

        display = print(data_filtered)
        print(display)
        print("\n remaining requests:", games.headers["x-requests-remaining"])
        print("\n number of requests you've used:", games.headers["x-requests-used"])


# LABELS

l1 = Label(
    sports_window,
    text="SportsBook, a place where you can see sports betting odds accross mutliple bookmakers!",
)
l1.grid(row=0, column=0)

l2 = Label(
    sports_window,
    text="List of Leagues: \n NBA -> basketball_nba \n WNBA -> basketball_wnba \n NFL -> americanfootball_nfl \n MLB -> baseball_mlb \n EPL -> soccer_epl \n FA CUP -> soccer_fa_cup \n FIFA WORLD CUP -> soccer_fifa_worldcup \n LIGUE 1 -> soccer_france_ligue_one \n BUNDESLIGA -> soccer_germany_bundesliga \n SERIES A -> soccer_italy_serie_a \n UEFA CHAMPIONS LEAGUE -> soccer_uefa_champs_league \n MLS -> soccer_usa_mls",
)
l2.grid(row=6, column=0)

# ENTRIES
odds_text = StringVar()
e1 = Entry(sports_window, textvariable=odds_text)
e1.grid(row=8, column=0)

# BUTTONS
b1 = Button(sports_window, text="GET ODDS", width=12, command=get_odds)
b1.grid(row=9, column=0)

# LISTBOX & SCROLL BAR
listb1 = Listbox(sports_window, height=6, width=35)
listb1.grid(row=10, column=0, rowspan=6, columnspan=6)

sbar1 = Scrollbar(sports_window)
sbar1.grid(row=10, column=3, rowspan=6)

sports_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: your request is getting a 404 response. Unfortunately can't help without knowing your params inputs (API KEY, REGIONS, etc.)

Comment: @chitown88 Sorry forgot to include the rest of the code.

Comment: Have you verified that `f"https://api.the-odds-api.com/v4/sports/{SPORT}/odds" + sportsodds_endpoint` results in a correct URL?

Comment: and what SPORT are you selecting that returns this error?

Answer (score 0):

The url is incorrect.
Also note I changed `REIGONS` to `REGIONS` Try:

```
sportsodds_endpoint = e1.get()  # !!!!!!!!
url = f"https://api.the-odds-api.com/v4/sports/{sportsodds_endpoint}/odds"
print(url)
games = requests.get(url
    ,
    params={
        "api_key": API_KEY,
        "regions": REGIONS,
        "markets": MARKETS,
        "oddsFormat": ODDS_FORMAT,
        "dateFormat": DATE_FORMAT,
    },
)
```

There's also a few things I'd change here. Take a look at this code and see if you have questions:

```
import requests



import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import requests
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

sports_window = Tk()
sports_window.wm_title("SportsBook")

pd.set_option("display.max_columns", 100)
pd.set_option("display.width", 1000000)

API_KEY = "YOUR_API_KEY"

SPORT = "upcoming"
REGIONS = "us"
MARKETS = "h2h"
ODDS_FORMAT = "american"
DATE_FORMAT = "iso"

def get_odds():
    sportsodds_endpoint = league_key.get()
    print(f"Getting odds for {sportsodds_endpoint}")
    url = f"https://api.the-odds-api.com/v4/sports/{sportsodds_endpoint}/odds"
    print(url)
    
    payload = {
        "apiKey": API_KEY,
        "regions": REGIONS,
        "markets": MARKETS,
        "oddsFormat": ODDS_FORMAT,
        "dateFormat": DATE_FORMAT,
    }
    
    games = requests.get(url, params=payload)
    

    if games.status_code != 200:
        print(
            f"failed to get odds: status code {games.status_code}, response body {games.text}"
        )
        # GRABS GAME'S TIMES, MATCHUP, AND ODDS BASED OFF OF LEAGUE/SPORT_KEY ENTRY
    else:
        print('Got data')
        games_json = games.json()
        games_df = pd.DataFrame(games_json)
        league = sportsodds_endpoint
        # FOR LOOP INTERATING OVER THE ENTIRE DF, THEN GRABS LIST OF GAME/ODD DATA BASED OFF OF ENTRY IF VALID ENTRY IS ENTERED

        data_filtered = games_df[games_df["sport_key"] == league]

            # PRINTS GAME DATA ^^^^^

        
        print(data_filtered)
        print("\n remaining requests:", games.headers["x-requests-remaining"])
        print("\n number of requests you've used:", games.headers["x-requests-used"])


# LABELS

l1 = Label(
    sports_window,
    text="SportsBook, a place where you can see sports betting odds accross mutliple bookmakers!",
)
l1.grid(row=0, column=0)

# Set up league options

league_options = requests.get(f'https://api.the-odds-api.com/v4/sports/?apiKey={API_KEY}').json()
league_options = {each['title']:each['key'] for each in league_options}

# This variable will hold the selected league key
league_key = StringVar()

# Create a canvas and scrollbar for the radio buttons
canvas = Canvas(sports_window)
canvas.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='news')

scrollbar = Scrollbar(sports_window, command=canvas.yview)
scrollbar.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='ns')

frame = Frame(canvas)
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame, anchor='nw')

canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

# This variable will hold the selected league key
league_key = StringVar(value='none')

# Create a radio button for each league
for name, key in league_options.items():
    Radiobutton(frame, text=name, variable=league_key, value=key).pack(anchor='w')

# Update scrollregion after configuring the canvas size
frame.update_idletasks()
canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'))

# BUTTONS
b1 = Button(sports_window, text="GET ODDS", width=12, command=get_odds)
b1.grid(row=2, column=0)  # Update this row number as needed

# LISTBOX & SCROLL BAR
listb1 = Listbox(sports_window, height=6, width=35)
listb1.grid(row=3, column=0, rowspan=6, columnspan=6)

sbar1 = Scrollbar(sports_window)
sbar1.grid(row=3, column=3, rowspan=6)

sports_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and input @chitown88, would you happen to know what the corresponding integer values are for the string indices on this line: `league_options = {each['title']:each['key'] for each in league_options}`

Comment: Not sure I know what you mean by integer values. 

That’s a dictionary. It’s essentially your MLB -> baseball_mlb part. Only difference is it’s not hard coded. It gets all those values from the api.

Comment: after updating the code with your changes I get this error when I run it 
`league_options = {each["title"]: each["key"] for each in league_options}
TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: What is the line you have right before the line that throws that error?

Comment: @CalebOnuonga or just email me the code and I can point out the error/fix. Jason.schvach@gmail.com

Comment: I will go ahead and email you the code, Thank you!